# iTunes songs play fine on PC, but stop midway on iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, ipod-nano

Certain songs will stop playing midway through.  The counter keeps progressing as though the song is still playing, but no audio. The same song plays fine on iTunes on the PC.  I wiped my iPhone (I only use it as an iPod) and reloaded my entire library.  Same issue.  Found an old iPod Nano.  Wiped it and reloaded the library.  Same song, same issue.  So 2 pieces of hardware have the same problem, yet the original file plays fine on iTunes on the PC

Comment: Try re-converting to another format & test again - File Menu/Convert [will only offer to convert to another format if already set in prefs/General/Import Settings...]

Comment: Song is an .m4p (protected), so cannot convert. As a test, I deleted the file from itunes and from the devices and purchased a new copy from the itunes store.  It is now an .m4a, Synched to the ipod and now song plays normally.

Comment: Will try a couple more.  Of course re-purchasing all these messed up songs again is not really an option...

Comment: You ought to be able to re-download without further purchase. Some songs you should be able to get m4a instead, these days